# How to add box-shadow to bootstrap carousel image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a inset `box-shadow` over my images in a bootstrap carousel but whatever I do it doesn't work. I want the shadow just around the borders of the image.

**Here is my code:**

```css
.carousel-item {
    width: 100%;
}
.carousel-item>a>img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
}
.carousel-item>a>img::after {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px 40px black inset;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div id="content"> 

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <a href="/2/">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <a href="/4/">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <a href="/3/">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Did you link your own stylesheet? Because in the code provided you haven't.

Comment: yes I did. I don't know how to do it in SO snippets. @Matt.S

Comment: I found this link: https://www.codeply.com/go/HTKVcweqHB/bootstrap-carousel-with-inset-shadow might help you out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [CSS Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors):

> The ':before' and ':after' pseudo-elements can be used to insert
>   generated content before or after an element's content.

Since an `img` doesn't have actual content, it makes sense that `::before` and `::after` cannot be accessed here.

One thing you can do is add a wrapper around the `img` and proceed from there.

```css
.img-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.img-container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px 40px black inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="">
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Laqtx8d/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try working with box shadow in negative (-). Instead using it on ::after use it on the image.

```css
.carousel-item>a>img {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px -60px -40px black inset;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

When having box shadow over a carousel item, it means the shadow will also move. You can also put the shadow over the carousel. This means the images will slide behind the shadow.

If you can add a working snippet(it does not work for me) i can try to give you code.